I need Help to evaluate :$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left({\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}}\right)^2\frac{1}{(2n+4)^2}$
I need Help to evaluate :$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left({\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}}\right)^2\frac{1}{(2n+4)^2}$$
we  have :
$$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\cos^{2n+2}(x)dx=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\sin^{2n+2}(x)dx=\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}$$
therfore:
$$S=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^{2n+2}(x)\sin^{2n+2}(y)}{(2n+4)^2}dxdy$$
let $t:=\cos^2(x)\sin^2(y)$
therfore:
$$S=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n+1}}{4(n+2)^2}dxdy$$
How to evaluate this :$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n+1}}{4(n+2)^2}$$

Why do you think the given sum would have an explicit form? The general way of solving such series: let $S(t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{t^{n+2}}{4(n+2)}$, hence $S'(t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{t^{n+1}}{4(n+2)} \Rightarrow (S'(t)t)' = \sum_{n \ge 0} t^{n+1}$. Therefore, you'll obtain an ODE to solve.

$Li_2 (t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n^2}$. You can obtain an integral expression: $- \ln (1-t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n}$. So that
$- \int^t_0 \dfrac{\ln (1-t)}{t} dt = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n^2}$ Then $- \int^t_0 \dfrac{\ln (1-t)}{t} dt = Li_2 (t)$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left({\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}}\right)^2\frac{x^n}{(2n+4)^2}=\frac 1 \pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma (n+2)^2}\,\frac{x^n}{(2n+4)^2}$$
As usual with gamma function in denominator, the result is
a Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\frac 1 {x^2} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2};1;x\right)-\frac{x+4}{4 x^2}$$
which is also
$$\frac{4 \left(\frac{2 (x-1) }{\pi }K(x)+\frac{4
   }{\pi }E(x)\right)-(x+4)}{4 x^2}$$ where appear  elliptic integrals.
Make $x=1$ to get a very nice result.
